# How to scan raw resources?

Tags: android

Is it possible to scan the raw resource folder and obtain a list of all the files in it? Or do I have to list all the files I want to use explicitly in my App?

Therefore, is the only possibility to access raw resources with

```
R.raw.<identifier>
```

or is it possible to somehow obtain a list of everything in `R.raw.*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to list down files from raw resource folder. But if you know the filenames, you can fetch from the identifier as:

```
int imageResource1 = getResources().getIdentifier("image1", "raw", getPackageName());

imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageResource1);
```

Where "image1" is the name of some png image file inside Raw folder.

See if this works for you assuming that you have serialised naming to your files, for example, image1.png, image2.png, etc